# UIImageView in UITableViewCell only appears after scrolling out of vision?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I added a `UIImageView` to my table view cell and I'm accessing it through the cell's `viewWithTag` method. If I just add it to the cell's content view and then run the app, the image view is there, nothing wrong with it. But then I want to apply a few lines of code to that image view to make it a rounded image view:

```
myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = myImageView.layer.frame.size.width / 2
myImageView.clipsToBounds = true
myImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
```

It looks fine, but the problem is that after I add these lines of code, the `UIImageView` doesn't appear until I scroll down my table view and then scroll back up to make a cell re-appear again. So basically it means the image view only gets loaded from the SECOND time a cell is being displayed. How can I make sure the `UIImageView` is already visible from the first time a cell needs to be displayed by the table view?

Comment: where did you add those lines of code? in `cellForItem atIndex` delegate method?

Comment: @MikeG `cellForRowAtIndexPath` if that's what you mean, yes.

Comment: yes, it has been modified in Swift 3 sorry for confusion. I remember having an issue just like this but I can't recall exactly how I solved it. Could you please add the rest of your code for the table view class?

Comment: @MikeG Why? The rest of the code doesn't add anything and has nothing to do with my image view or this problem. What are you hoping to find in the rest of my code?

Answer (score 0):

Make a subclass for your tableview cell and set it in your storyboard:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
      // your border and corner radius settings
   }
 }
```

The problem is that you are settings these properties in the wrong time in the cell's lifecycle. With this approach it's gonna work properly.

Update: an other solution might be to use IBInspectables in storyboard and set these in the Attributes Inspector. See the attached image and code below.

[image]

```
extension UIView {

  @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
  }

  @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.borderWidth
    }
    set {
        layer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
  }

  @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor {
    get {
        guard let borderc = layer.borderColor else {
            return UIColor()
        }
        return UIColor(CGColor: borderc)
    }
    set {
        layer.borderColor = newValue.CGColor
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there no way of calling `layoutSubviews()` manually? I have 8 prototype cells which all include at least 6 subviews, so I can only imagine how overkill it would be to rebuild my entire table view from scratch just to get some image views to appear like they should.

Comment: It's not overkill at all, because layoutSubviews() will be called automatically. This is simply the way how you can layout borders and radiuses. If you need to call this manually, I would suggest to do this after you set up your UI in the cell. So, in the cellForIndexPath delegate method, before you would return your cell do simply: cell.layoutSubviews()

Comment: Tried both suggestions and none of them worked. I also tried calling `layoutSubviews()` in `cellWillDisplayAtIndexPath` but it didn't have any effect either. I don't understand how setting label texts and stuff like that are immediately visible according to the data provided in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but somehow image view data needs to be set at a later point in time. It doesn't make any sense, unless the reason it's not showing is in the code itself and not in the moment the code gets executed. Aren't labels/buttons/sliders, etc. subviews of a cell as well, just like image views?

Comment: Call this in cellForRowAtIndexPath before returning the cell.

Comment: I did. That's where I have been calling it all along. The code in my post was taken from my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: I updated my answer, hope this helps. Just use this on the uiview you want to modify.